# Restart every minute

Tags: rig

I need help from anyone..
My ethereum mining rig having 6 Rx470 cards, get restart every minute,
When I reduce Mhs of few cards it keep running for some time...
Pls give me suggestions ,How can I resolve this

Comment: Hi there. You mean the hardware is reset, or the mining software/process? Which software are you using, and on which platform?

Comment: Did you check if your power source have enough to feed all your equiment when functioning?